# After instantiating c++ object in QML its parent is null

Tags: qt, qml, hierarchy, qobject

I can't catch why:

1. Have a c++ constructor realization

```
Class::Constructor (QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
...
qDebug() << parent;
}
```

The Class is inherited from QObject and contains Q_OBJECT macro as well.

2. in main.cpp I have registered a QML type for Class: `qmlRegisterType<>(Blablabla...)`
3. in QML separate `module.qml` I have an implementation:

```
import blablbla 1.0

Blablabla

{

id: abc

 console.log(parent)

}
```

Everything works fine, but `console.log` gives me the real parent object (not null), while `qDebug()` gives me null. What's about `QObject` hierarchy here?

P.S. the `module.qml` object is created via js `QtCreateComponent -> createObject(parent, args)`

Comment: Please give us a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: QML doesn't expose the `QObject` parent, there is no `parent` property for `QtObject`. The `parent` you see is actually the `parentItem` and is only present for visual items - `QQuickItem` or `Item` in QML naming, which is also the type of the parent.

Comment: "QML doesn't expose the QObject parent, there is no parent property for QtObject" - that's what I needed. Thank you! Yes, of course via console.log I see the visual Item (Item).